# Javascript element.reportValidity() function preventing leaving input

Tags: javascript, html, validation

So I have an HTML form with a bunch of inputs. I am using the following for custom validation:

```
ConfirmPasswordFieldValidation(sender)
{
    if(sender.target.value != this.confirmPasswordField.value)
        sender.target.className = "isGood";
    else
    {
        sender.target.className = "isBad";
        sender.target.setCustomValidity("Passwords don't match.");
        sender.target.reportValidity();
    }

    this.CheckReadiness();
}
```

So the reportValidity() function does what I want it to but as long as the custom message is present, I cannot tab out of the field that has input focus. Is there a way to both display a custom message and allow for input focus to be elsewhere simultaneously?

Comment: "So the reportValidity() function does what I want it to but as long as the custom message is present" - `reportValidity` is __non-blocking__. Share what `CheckReadiness` is doing in your code example.

Comment: CheckReadiness just enables the submit button if all of the input fields have a certain class.

Comment: It is non-blocking, but chrome and safari put the focus on the invalid field. So if you use reportValidity() in blur or focusout event, chrome and safari keep you trapped. So far, what I've found is you have to disable form default validation and implement your own.